# Why won't my iPhone modal or form elements work unless they are positioned at the top of my iPhone screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Very hard to even properly phrase this Q. If you go to http://druvocals.com
and scroll down the title "IT'S OH, SO EASY", you will see a graphic and then "Choose your options". Under that is a "Learn more" link which is a modal trigger.

Works fine on Desktop and my Android phone, but the link only works on the iPhone IF you tap it when it's positioned at the top of the phone's screen. Strangest thing ever. Tried in both Safari and Chrome for iOS. If the link is in the middle of the phone's screen, the modal won't trigger. [Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwEGu.jpg)

Comment: Just noticed that the modal also triggers if the link is way at the bottom of the screen. So, it's working at the top and bottom of the screen, but not anywhere in the middle, which is where a user is most likely to try and tap it.

Comment: Ok, now just realized that this goes for ALL links, not just a modal popup. I even put a test link right when you view the page for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

Support team for the theme let me know that it was a bug in the current version. Updated and all is good.